# Renaming the folders by removing a specific string prefix to their names using for loop in cmd

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I have 16 folders like:

```
Sample-2.1-1
Sample-2.2-1
Sample-2.3-1
.....
Sample-2.16-1
```

Those are inside a folder SVN for example

```
D:\SVN\Sample-2.1-1
D:\SVN\Sample-2.2-1
D:\SVN\Sample-2.3-1
.....
D:\SVN\Sample-2.16-1
```

Now I want to rename all these 16 folders by removing `Sample-` in their names such as:

```
2.1-1
2.2-1
2.3-1
.....
2.16-1
```

How could I do it using for command inside [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd).

Comment: Please try something and let us know what happens.  We aren't here to write the code for you.  Consider looking up `for /f` command using `delims=-`.

Comment: I tried something like  `set dirname="D:\SVN" &&  for /d "tokens=1,2 delims=- "%%G in ('dir /b %dirname%') do rename %dirname%\%%G-%%H %%H  ` where %%G is the string before delimiter and %%H is string after delimiter. But it gives me error like   " in was unexpected at this time." .

Comment: You need `for /f`, not `for /d`.  Also put a space between the double quote and %%G.

Comment: with command  `set dirname=D:\SVN && for /f  "tokens=1,2 delims=-"  %G in (' dir /b %dirname%') do rename %dirname%\%G-%H-1 %H-1`   i get  `rename D:\SVN  \Sample-2.2-1 2.2-1` on the cmd. It means i get a space between `rename D:\SVN` and `\Sample-2.2-1` instead of `rename D:\SVN \Sample-2.2-1 2.2-1`  i get `rename D:\SVN  \Sample-2.2-1 2.2-1`. If cmd is able to get command without space everything would be fine i guess

Comment: `ren "%dirname%\%G-%H" "%H"`

Comment: hi thanks for the help i figured it out, the reason was just one & between both commands.

Answer (score 1):

```
pushd "d:\svn"
for /f "tokens=1*" %%A in ('dir /b /ad sample-*') do ren "%%A-%%B" "%%B"
popd
```

Or, in the off chance that you have a folder name like `sample--xxxx`, then

```
pushd "d:\svn"
for /d %%F in (sample-*) do for /f "tokens=1*" %%A in ("%%F") do ren "%%F" "%%B"
popd
```